# ¿Como insertar un cuadro de texto (Text) pero usando Ttk() en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy aprendiendo a crear interfaces gráficas en Python usando tkinter y tengo el siguiente código en el cual quiero **insertar un cuadro de texto para comentarios**, pero siempre me genera error **a partir de la linea 58**. Quiero hacerlo a través de Ttk(), y no Tk().

No logro entender que es lo que pasa. He usado tanto Text(), como TextArea() y ninguno me funciona. Les agradezco mucho.

En esta ocasion estoy usando ttk() porque este modulo ofrece mejoras visuales con respecto a tk() y quiero aprender a manejarlo.

Aquí mi código:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Aplicacion:
    """En el método __init__ inmediatamente luego de crear el objeto de la clase Tk procedemos a crear el 
        primer LabelFrame y ubicarlo dentro de la ventana:"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.ventana1=tk.Tk()

        s = ttk.Style()

        #s.configure('Red.TLabelframe.Label', font=('Roboto Cn', 15, 'bold'))
        s.configure('Red.TLabelframe.Label', font=('Roboto Condensed', 12))
        s.configure('Red.TLabelframe.Label', foreground ='green')
        #s.configure('Red.TLabelframe.Label', background='blue')

        #lf = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text = "Test", style = "Red.TLabelframe")

        self.labelframe1=ttk.LabelFrame(self.ventana1, text="DATOS USUARIO :", style = "Red.TLabelframe")        
        self.labelframe1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=10)        
        """Para no hacer todo el algoritmo dentro del método __init__ implementamos el método login (aparte)
        y desde acá hacemos su llamada:"""
        self.login()

        self.labelframe2=ttk.LabelFrame(self.ventana1, text="OPERACIONES: ", style = "Red.TLabelframe")        
        self.labelframe2.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=5, pady=10)        
        self.operaciones()

        self.ventana1.mainloop()

    # Implementamos el método login:
    # El algoritmo del método login tiene por objetivo crear las 2 Label, 2 Entry y Button
    # y añadirlos dentro del LabelFrame:
    def login(self):

        self.label1=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Nombre:")
        self.label1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4, sticky="w")
        self.entry1=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, width=40)
        self.entry1.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.label1=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Apellidos:")
        self.label1.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=4, sticky="w")
        self.entry1=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, width=40)
        self.entry1.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.label1=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Direccion:")
        self.label1.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=4, pady=4, sticky="w")
        self.entry1=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, width=40)
        self.entry1.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.label2=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Password:")        
        self.label2.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=4, pady=4, sticky="w")
        self.entry2=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, show="*", width=20)
        self.entry2.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=4, pady=4, sticky="w")

        self.label2=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Comentarios:")        
        self.label2.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=4, pady=4, sticky="w")
        self.textoComentario=ttk.Text(labelframe1, width=30, height=5)
        self.textoComentario.grid(column=1, row=4,  padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

        self.scrollVert=Scrollbar(miFrame, command=textoComentario.yview)
        self.scrollVert.grid(column=2, row=4,  sticky="nsew")

        self.textoComentario.config(yscrollcommand=scrollVert.set)


    # Implementamos el método operaciones:
    # El método operaciones crea los 3 Button y los agrega al segundo LabelFrame:
    def operaciones(self):

        self.boton2=ttk.Button(self.labelframe2, text="Agregar usuario")
        self.boton2.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.boton3=ttk.Button(self.labelframe2, text="Modificar usuario")
        self.boton3.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.boton4=ttk.Button(self.labelframe2, text="Borrar usuario")
        self.boton4.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)

aplicacion1=Aplicacion()
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, entiendo. En ultimas lo que necesito es que el código de la linea 58 en adelante funcione. Si gusta pruébelo para que se de cuenta el error que me sale, y me indique por favor como corregirlo. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No existe una versión para `Text` o `TextArea` en `ttk`. El widget `Text` realmente no hay mucho que mejorar en cuanto a estilo, solo es un área en la que ingresar texto.

Si no me salto alguno, los widgets que ofrece ttk son `Button`, `Checkbutton`, `Entry`, `Combobox`, `Spinbox`, `Frame`, `LabeledScale`, `Label`, `Labelframe`, Menubutton, `OptionMenu`, `Notebook`, `Panedwindow`, `Progressbar`, `Radiobutton`, Scale, Scrollbar, `Separator` y `Sizegrip`. ¿Hay algo en especial en cuanto a apariencia que quisieras y no puedes obtener con tkinter.Text?

Usa simplemente tkinter.Text, aunque unas observaciones:

- Te falta anteponer `self.` a varias nombres en el método login, así como `tk.` o `ttk.` para `Scrollbar`.
- Siempre que agregues barras de desplazamineto a un widget usa un frame para agrupar el widget y sus barras. Las barras y el widget deben en principio formar siempre un todo e ir unidas.

---

```
def login(self):

    self.label1=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Nombre:")
    self.label1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4, sticky="w")
    self.entry1=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, width=40)
    self.entry1.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)

    self.label1=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Apellidos:")
    self.label1.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=4, sticky="w")
    self.entry1=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, width=40)
    self.entry1.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)

    self.label1=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Direccion:")
    self.label1.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=4, pady=4, sticky="w")
    self.entry1=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, width=40)
    self.entry1.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)

    self.label2=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Password:")        
    self.label2.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=4, pady=4, sticky="w")
    self.entry2=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, show="*", width=20)
    self.entry2.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=4, pady=4, sticky="w")

    self.label2=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Comentarios:")        
    self.label2.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=4, pady=4, sticky="w")

    text_frame = tk.Frame(self.labelframe1)
    self.textoComentario=tk.Text(text_frame, width=30, height=5)
    self.textoComentario.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, side=tk.LEFT)
    self.scrollVert=ttk.Scrollbar(text_frame, command=self.textoComentario.yview)
    self.scrollVert.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT)
    text_frame.grid(column=1, row=4,  padx=10, pady=10, sticky="we")

    self.textoComentario.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollVert.set)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias amigo, voy a revisar y probar. Muchos saludos.